# HTML email template

Tags: php, html, email

Based on several different sources, I have compiled the following as my basic HTML email template.  Please let me know if I have missed anything important.  I am not sure if I am using `\n` and `\r\n` correctly.

```
$semi_rand = uniqid();
$mime_boundary = "==MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_$semi_rand";
$mime_boundary_header = chr(34) . $mime_boundary . chr(34);
$boundary = "nextPart";
$headers = "From: ".$from."\n";
$headers .= "To: ". $to ."\n";
$headers .= "CC: ". $CC ." \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <". $data['from'] .">\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header ;
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n"; // beginning \n added to separate previous content
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";

$body = "

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

". strip_tags($message) ."

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

". chunk_split(base64_encode(
  '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'.
  $style.'</head><body>'.$message.'</body></html>'  )) ."

--$mime_boundary--";

mail(null,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f".$email);
```

Questions:

1. Will switching `base64_encode()` to `quoted_printable_encode()` work or will I also need to convert the string to an 8-bit string somehow?
2. Should I just remove these extra headers?
3. Could/should I use `\r\n\` at every line break, including the ones in the multiline string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some notes:

**base64**

It's not usual to `base64_encode` HTML. While the way you've done it will work, you run the risk of being marked as spam as spam filters see attempts at obfuscating emails as shady. Consider Quoted-Printable instead.

**$boundary?**

This section doesn't make sense:

```
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n"; // beginning \n added to separate previous content
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
```

You are correctly defining and using `$mime_boundary_header`, these extra headers are unnecessary and will break the email.

**New Lines**

You've ended 'To' and 'From' with `"\n"`, these should be `"\r\n"`. You're also using a multiline string for `$body`. This is ok, but make sure your text editor is using `CRLF` (`"\r\n"`) for new lines.

**To**

You still need to pass `$to` into `mail()` as the email 'To' header and the recipient can technically be different:

`mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f".$email);`

**Extra Notes**
*(This is stuff that doesn't really matter)*

- The way you generate `$semi_rand` is acceptable, but you might want to consider using `uniqid()` instead
- If your return-path and reply-to values are the same as your from, you don't need to specify them

## Edits in Light of New Questions

**Base 64 to Quoted Printable**

> Will switching base64_encode() to quoted_printable_encode() or will I also need to convert the string to an 8-bit string somehow?

The PHP function `quoted_printable_encode()` will do that for you - quoted printable is designed to produce 7bit output

Make sure you also update the header to `Content-Transfer-Encoding:quoted-printable` as well

**Removing Unnecessary headers**

> Should I just remove these extra headers?

Yes, they aren't required for anything

**New Lines**

> Could/Should I use \r\n\ at every line break, including the ones in the multiline string?

You don't *have* to if you're sure your text editor will use `CRLF`s, however I prefer to explicitly use `"\r\n"` for my emails, as you have done for the `$headers` variable, as it tends to be clearer and reduces the risk of the line endings being changed if you / someone else ever resaves the file with a different editor, etc